# How to compare matlab array with entries in a data structure

Tags: string, matlab, for-loop, data-structures, strcmp

I am trying to write code in Matlab that will allow me to do the following. There is a part of the code that generates an array D and uses an input file to create this structure called EEG which contains a lot of information. Specifically I am interested in a "labels" field of the chanlocs field of the EEG structure. It contains entries like 'F7', 'F8', 'FP1'... and 17 such entries. The array D that is generated also contains entries like this but in a different order.

So for e.g. D = ['F7','F8', 'FP1'] and EEG.chanlocs.labels = ['FP1','F7','F8']
they contain the same entries but they are in a different order and for what I am trying to do the order is important.

What I basically want to do is to have Matlab scan all entries of D and find that particular index of EEG.chanlocs.labels to which that entry corresponds. 
Example: If D(1) = 'F7' I want it to return for e.g. i = 2 because F7 is the 2nd entry in EEG.chanlocs.labels. In this way I want it to scan all of D and return the indices in EEG.chanlocs.labels.

What I have tried so far is:

```
for i=1:17
    if any(strcmp(D(:),[EEG.chanlocs(i).labels]))
    msgbox(sprintf('i is: %d',i));
 else
     msgbox(sprintf('Error'));
 end 
 end
```

But it does not work and it returns weird things... I am not entirely sure what to try...

Can anybody help? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks.

Edited:

The following code shows how I obtain D. I give the user 3 prompt windows to input certain data. I then store the inputs from each of these in "data" or "data2" or "data3" and then I put all of them together in D.

```
uiwait(msgbox(sprintf('Please enter your new references for each     electrode.\nFor FP1, FP2, O1 and O2 provide two references.')));
prompt = {'Fp1','F7','T3','T5','O1'};
prompt2 = {'FP2','F8','T4','T6','O2'};
prompt3 = {'C3','CP3','Cz','CPz','C4','CP4'};
dlg_title = 'Input references';
num_lines = 1;
%def = {'20','hsv'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines );
answer2 = inputdlg(prompt2,dlg_title,num_lines );
answer3 = inputdlg(prompt3,dlg_title,num_lines );
for i=1:5    
   data(i,:) = answer(i,:); 
   data2(i,:) = answer2(i,:);

end

for i=1:6    
 data3(i,:) = answer3(i,:);

end

D(1:5)=data(:);
D(6:10)=data2(:);
D(11:16)=data3(:);
D=D';
```

Comment: Are they stored in a cell array or an array as you wrote above? Because defining D as you did above creates a character of length 7. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Benoit_11 I have added the part of the code where I obtain D... I want them to be arrays...